# JQuery, adding row but no effect on className

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a row to existing table by using clone() method. It is working fine and I also want to change CSS class name for all div elements under each td from the original row. Basically I want to make some td elements as editable. I have tried this by adding "row.find("td div")..." as you see in the code, but this code has no effect at all. Any suggestions?

```
 $("#create_blank_scenario").click(function(){
                var row = $('#sortable_offer_table tbody tr:first').clone(true);

                row.find("td div").addClass("editable");

                row.insertBefore('#sortable_offer_table tbody tr:first');
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is an issue with your markup, as your code seems to be working just fine for me.  Here's a demo of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/gkEbp/

I created some dummy html:

```
<table id="sortable_offer_table">
    <tr>
        <td><div>My Text</div></td>
        <td><div>My Other Text</div></td>
        <td><div>My Final Text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div>My Text</div></td>
        <td><div>My Other Text</div></td>
        <td><div>My Final Text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div>My Text</div></td>
        <td><div>My Other Text</div></td>
        <td><div>My Final Text</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br/><br/>

<button type="button" id="create_blank_scenario">Create Blank</button>
```

Added a CSS rule to highlight `.editable` and ran your code against it.  As you can see, it works.

Comment: Yes you are right, problem with markup and editable css. Corrected and working fine

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there's something wrong with the selector. I'd run `row.find("td div")` and check its `length` (an `alert()` will do) to make sure you're actually finding the div you want.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure, but I would try adding the class *after* inserting the row into the DOM.